# fiddler - can I output requesting client ip/name?

Tags: fiddler

Using the code here shows how to add a column:

http://fiddler2.com/documentation/KnowledgeBase/FiddlerScript/AddColumns

What I'd like to know, though, is the ip (or name) of the client issuing the request.  Is that possible to determine?

Thanks,
Ben

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can grab this off Session object that is passed in. So in the code example in the article you link to you would set the value of you column to oS.clientIP.

Answer (score 0):

For convenience the complete code you have to insert into the `Handlers` class:

```
  public static BindUIColumn("ClientIP")
    function ColClientIP(oS: Session){
        return oS.clientIP; 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is now available from the UI using Customise Columns and the session flag X-clientIP. Now means V5.0.20211 of Fiddler Classic. Probably been there for some time.